# What is the origin of a Hungarian word cápa (shark)

Tags: etymology, hungarian

The word for shark in Hungarian is **cápa**. Quick search for its origin didn't bring me anything. Probably there are some Hungarian sources, but I don't know the language, unluckily.

As Hungary is a continental nation (even taking into account the Great Migration), they probably didn't had much experience with sharks in the past. So, there should be an origin for that word – either from other language or from some related subject. What is the origin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Hungarian etymological dictionary I have found, *Etimológiai szótár. Magyar szavak és toldalékok eredete*, Zaicz Gábor, Budapest, 2006, [p. 104](https://regi.tankonyvtar.hu/hu/tartalom/tinta/TAMOP-4_2_5-09_Etimologiai_szotar/Etimologiai_szotar_104_104.html), it is said that **cápa**, first attested at the end of the 18th century, stems from an older, now obsolete, 16th century word *capa* meaning ‘[shagreen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shagreen)’, a kind of leather made from the skin of a shark:

> **cápa** [1794] Valószínűleg szóhasadással keletkezett az elavult *capa* ’sagrenbőr’ [1529] szóból, a sagrenbőrt ugyanis cápabőrből készítik. Az is lehetséges, hogy a 18. század végén tudatos állattani műszói alkotásként keletkezett. Eredeti, ’ragadozó tengeri hal’ jelentése alapján hasonlóságon alapuló névátvitellel keletkezett az ’öreg matróz’, illetve a
> ’kíméletlen kizsákmányoló’ jelentése.

Interesting to note, that in the neighboring Czech and Slovak languages, also very continental, the word for ‘shark’ is *[žralok](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%BEralok)*  “eater, devourer”, derived from the verb *žrát/žrát’* “to eat (of animals)”, analogous to the German [fressen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fressen#German) as opposed to [essen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/essen#German) “to eat (of people)”.

Comment: Well, words for shark are often strange in many languages. For example, Russian word _акула_ probably comes from some word for shark liver oil.

Comment: @SergeyKirienko - I wouldn't say they're strange, they're mostly neutral ‘big fish’ (Latin ‘squalus’, cognate of English ‘whale’) or related to the predator nature of sharks: Arabic قِرْش‎ (qirš) “chewer, grinder”, Turkish ‘köpek balığı’ “dog fish”. Russian ‘акула’ is a borrowing from Old Norse ‘hákarl’, whichever way it took.